# Maximum date that can be stored in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to store date like **"247530526765-12-27"** in DB. But I am getting the following error **IO Error pq: date/time field value out of range: "247530526765-12-27"**

I understand the year field of my date is too odd. But still I want to know whether it is possible. If yes, how do I increase the maximum range of DATE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Postgres's [`date` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) is only 4 bytes wide, so it can't store anything beyond the year 5874897. There is not a way to increase it.

With a little work in your client, you could store the date in a wide [numeric type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) like a `bigint` as "days from epoch" or something similar. Or you could always serialize the date to a string.

Comment: people living in 5874898: 